# Evaluate an expression in print statement

Tags: python

```
>>>line=['hello',' this',' is', 'a',' test']  
>>>print line
['hello', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

But i want that when line is printed, it should be a whole string and not like elements of a list.
This is what i tried:

```
>>> print line[k] for k in len(line)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can this list line can be printed as a string?

Comment: `print ' '.join(line)`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to concatenate strings in python. If you have a list and want to concatenate its contents, the preferred way is usually `.join(list)`.

```
line=['hello',' this',' is', ' a',' test']
print ''.join(line)
```

For more ways see http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python

If you wanted to use a for loop (not recommended, but possible) you could do something like

```
line=['hello',' this',' is', ' a',' test']
concatenated_line = ''

for word in line:
    concatenated_line += word

print concatenated_line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line=['hello',' this',' is', 'a',' test'] 
str1 = ' '.join(line)
print str1
# hello this is a test
```

Comment: But i want this to be printed in the same line with other things as well

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.